# Can this power tower function be optimized to perform faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation

Take the following function defined in Mathematica:

```
Itr[x_, p_, n_] := x^Nest[Power[p, #] &, 1, n];
```

Evaluating this function even for small values of `p` results in very slow and processor-intensive evaluation. Is there an equivalent expression that will evaluate more efficiently and quickly?

For example, `Itr[3, 1/2, 25] // N` takes nearly 3 minutes to evaluate on a 2016 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use floating point numbers right from the start:

```
 Itr[3., 0.5, 50000000]
```

takes about one second on my machine.

You can also perform this in higher precision, but that will take longer; for example the following computation with 100-digit precision needs also about one second on my laptop:

```
 Itr[3.`100, 0.5`100, 500000];
```

Assuming that the nested powers converge quickly, one can also use `FixedPoint` in order to iterate as long as it is needed:

```
 f[x_, p_] := x^FixedPoint[Power[p, #] &, 1];
```

## Edit

Assuming that the sequence $x_{n+1} = p^{x_n}$ converges, towards an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the limit point $x$ has to be a fixed point of

$$\varPhi_p(x) = p^x.$$

We can use Mathematica to solve this fixed point equation:

```
ClearAll[x,p];
F[p_] = Simplify[x /. Solve[Power[p, x] == x][[1]], {p > 0}]
```

> -(ProductLog[-Log[p]]/Log[p])

So, we may use

```
f2[x_, p_] = x^F[p];
```

as even faster version. For example, we can compute 100000 limit points of `Itr` within a single second:

```
n = 100000;
x = RandomReal[{1, 40}, n];
p = RandomReal[{0.1, .9}, n];
data = f2[x, p]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.00969